# symfony2 controller needs two ways of return-values, one for symfony-application (inside symfony) one for mobile (json)

Tags: ajax, json, symfony, mobile-website

I'm trying to build a restful JSON api for my Symfony2 Application.

I'm using the http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer `JMS\Serializer` Bundle to serialize my Entities to `JSON`.

I have this example `Controller-Action`:

```
public function getFarmerByNameAction(Request $request) {
    $this->setLocale($request);

    $name = $request->get("name");
    $farmer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("FarmerguideBackendBundle:Farmer")->findByName($name);

    // Return json response
    return new Response($this->jsonify($farmer));
}
```

Since I'm using this serializer very often (I know I should do something like a singleton or whatever, but currently I don't have the time for that, I was just playing with the framework) I've put the code inside a function which does the serializing.

```
private function jsonify($object) {
        // Serialize to json
        $serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new
                JsonEncoder()));
        $json = $serializer->serialize($object, 'json');
        return $json;
}
```

**My problem is the following:**

- This code is inside a `BackendController`, which does NOT contain any gui-specific information. So just a RESTful API.
- In another Controller, let's say `WebappController` I have the code to access these backendfunctions and do some stuff with twig-files and `render()`-methods.
- I want to access all these information via **mobile** over ajax (therefore I need this json return value)

What's the **best-practice** here? Is it better to say: Well if it's a ajax-call (check with `if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())`) , do jsonify right before returning the repsonse and if it's not return the entities (I need entities for twig-templates..) Or is there another approach?

Or is it even better to work with `$request->getFormatType()` and making the ajax call with  `contentType="application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: Try [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle), it can [handle multiple formats for the same action](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-the-view-layer.md), including both JSON and TWIG templates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how KnpBundles handles it https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpBundles/blob/master/src/Knp/Bundle/KnpBundlesBundle/Controller/DeveloperController.php#L35

Comment: well, this looks not bad, but where is the format saved or submitted?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to clearify what your intentions are. Because right now it seems as if your `WebappController` would just be a client to your `Backendcontroller`. Something like:

`$result = file_get_contents('/path/to/backend/method/1/3');`

You then simply go ahead and decode the json.

That is some additional overhead of course. If you want to get entities, I would suggest to create a Service for all your backend methods and return the entities there. You then simply call those methods from your `BackendController` and your `WebappController`. You then would only jsonify the entities in your `BackendController` and render the appropriate templates in your `WebappController`.